# This code is running successfully in my system. But when I tried to run in other's system its not working

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
 
Sub CombineFiles()
     
    Dim path            As String
    Dim Filename        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
     
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    path = "C:\Users\Abins\Desktop\Payment Posting VBA 19062022\Consol" 'Change as needed
    Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until Filename = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
        For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets
            ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next ws
        Wkb.Close False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Success! Press Cntrl+J"
     
End Sub
```

I want to find a solution as this code is being used to combine multiple files from a folder that contains more than 80 excel workbook that each has three worksheets. its working fine on my system ( in my personal laptop, office system, and one colleague's system).

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what error and which line does it stop on?

Comment: I dont get any errors. it simply doesnt pull the files from the folder.  I only get the last code executed that is  MsgBox "Success! Press Cntrl+J"

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that starts the loop, and then check your variables as it goes. Also, are all the computer processing the same folders?

Comment: Okay I will try by break point. No bro same workbooks in different machine. it works well for me regardless in share folder or if I create a folder in my desktop

Comment: Is it possible that at the others the files are in the ```xlsx``` extension for example and not ```xls```?

Comment: I assume you changed `C:\Users\Abins\` on the other computer? As already mentioned tou need to use breakpoints/debugging. Likely simply no file matches your search.

Comment: set a debug.print Filename befor set Wkb plus a debug.print ws.name before ws.copy to see if the code finds workbooks - and sheets.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I change the location path based on the system

Comment: It might also help if you add the count of processed files in the message.

Answer (score 0):

### Import Worksheets

- It looks like there are no files in the folder unless your colleague has added an `On Error Resume Next` to the code when there could be any of the issues covered in the following procedure. Give it a try and share some feedback.
- Note that there is nothing wrong with your procedure.

```vb
Sub CombineFiles()
    Const ProcName As String = "CombineFiles"
    Dim ErrNumber As Long
    Dim ErrDescription As String
    Dim swbCount As Long
    Dim swsCount As Long
    Dim swsCountTotal As Long
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
     
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const USE_DESKTOP As Boolean = True
    Const DESKTOP_RELATIVE_PATH As String _
        = "Payment Posting VBA 19062022\Consol"
    Const SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.xls*"
     
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
     
    ' Build the source folder path.
    
    Dim SourceFolderPath As String
     
    If USE_DESKTOP Then
        ' Get the Desktop path.
        Dim DesktopPath As String
        DesktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & pSep & "Desktop" & pSep
        Dim DesktopName As String
        DesktopName = Dir(DesktopPath, vbDirectory)
        If Len(DesktopName) = 0 Then
            DesktopPath = Environ("OneDrive") & pSep & "Desktop" & pSep
            DesktopName = Dir(DesktopPath, vbDirectory)
            If Len(DesktopName) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Could not find the Desktop path.", vbCritical, ProcName
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        SourceFolderPath = DesktopPath & DESKTOP_RELATIVE_PATH
    Else ' don't use Desktop relative path
        SourceFolderPath = FOLDER_PATH
    End If
    
    If Right(SourceFolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then
        SourceFolderPath = SourceFolderPath & pSep
    End If
    
    Dim SourceFolderName As String
    SourceFolderName = Dir(SourceFolderPath, vbDirectory)
    If Len(SourceFolderName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path '" & SourceFolderPath & "' doesn't exist.", _
            vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Build the Dir pattern.
    Dim DirPattern As String
    DirPattern = SourceFolderPath & SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN
    
    ' Get the first file name.
    Dim SourceFileName As String: SourceFileName = Dir(DirPattern)
    If Len(SourceFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found matching the pattern '" & SOURCE_FILE_PATTERN _
            & "' in '" & SourceFolderPath & "'.", _
            vbExclamation, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    End If
     
    ' Reference the destination workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
     
    ' Open, copy & close.
     
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim SourceFilePath As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Do While Len(SourceFileName) > 0
        SourceFilePath = SourceFolderPath & SourceFileName
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SourceFilePath, True, True)
        swbCount = swbCount + 1
        swsCountTotal = swsCountTotal + swb.Worksheets.Count
        For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
            If Not sws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
                sws.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
                swsCount = swsCount + 1
            'Else ' it's very hidden; do nothing!?
            End If
        Next sws
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        SourceFileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    IsSuccess = True

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
        If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
        Dim CountMsg As String:
        CountMsg = vbLf & vbLf & "Workbooks processed: " & swbCount & vbLf _
            & "Worksheets copied: " & swsCount & "(" & swsCountTotal & ")"
        
        If IsSuccess Then
            MsgBox "Success! Press Ctrl+J" & CountMsg, vbInformation, ProcName
        Else
            MsgBox "Run-time error '" & ErrNumber & "':" _
                & vbLf & ErrDescription & CountMsg, vbCritical, ProcName
        End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

ClearError:
    ErrNumber = Err.Number
    ErrDescription = Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```